# Changing row value based on previous row value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Exist a data frame with events

|  | start_ event | end_event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-23 17:20 | 2023-09-23 17:40 |
| 2 | 2023-09-24 10:00 | 2023-09-24 10:20 |
| 3 | 2023-09-24 10:20 | 2023-09-24 10:40 |
| 4 | 2023-09-24 10:40 | 2023-09-24 11:00 |
| 5 | 2023-09-25 11:00 | 2023-09-25 11:20 |
| 6 | 2023-09-25 11:20 | 2023-09-25 11:40 |

Difference between *start_ event*    and *end_event* always 20 minutes. I need to group the data if a new event starts immediately after the previous one ends

|  | start_ event | end_event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-23 17:20 | 2023-09-23 17:40 |
| 2 | 2023-09-24 10:00 | 2023-09-24 11:00 |
| 3 | 2023-09-25 11:00 | 2023-09-25 11:40 |

the maximum duration of a event is one hour, there may be several events in one day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# convert start_event/end_event to datetime (if necessary):
df["start_event"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_event"])
df["end_event"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_event"])


out = df.groupby(
    (df["end_event"].diff() != pd.Timedelta("20 minutes")).cumsum(), as_index=False
).agg({"start_event": "first", "end_event": "last"})
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
          start_event           end_event
0 2023-09-23 17:20:00 2023-09-23 17:40:00
1 2023-09-24 10:00:00 2023-09-24 11:00:00
2 2023-09-25 11:00:00 2023-09-25 11:40:00
```